# Deploying Django Project with apache2

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Someone can help me why it doesn't work? (my project name is ikh)
i'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Apache2 , Python3

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/ikh

WSGIDaemonProcess ikh python-path=/var/www/ikh/  python-home=/var/www/ikh/.env
WSGIProcessGroup ikh
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/ikh/ikh/wsgi.py

<Directory /var/www/ikh/ikh>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>



ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found that some interesting problems :

1 - first should set server to listen the port that i want to deploy on it!

```
Listen 8000
```

2 - to use **WSGIDaemonProcess**  should do like this sample that i write it for my apache2 configuration

```
WSGIDaemonProcess ikh python-path=/var/www/ikh  python-home=/var/www/ikh/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

and thats about it!

Comment: (2) is incorrect, The ``python-home`` option should not be pointing at ``site-packages`` directory. See documentation on using virtual environment with mod_wsgi.  http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: You verified that what you were using was what ``sys.prefix`` was reported as in the Python interpreter for the virtual environment? It definitely should not be the ``site-packages`` directory for ``python-home``. Doing that would likely result in the Python interpreter failing on startup.